# how can i debug this issue with axis 2 web services and clients

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am learning to make web services with eclipse, apache and axis 2 following [this](http://blog.sencide.com/2011/06/create-web-service-using-apache-axis2.html) tutorial. I am able to generate web services, create and upload .aar files and generate web service clients just like in the tutorial. But when I go to test the client it is not generating proper responses...

```
 PersonalInfoServiceStub stub = new PersonalInfoServiceStub();
 GetContactInfo atn = new GetContactInfo();
 atn.setPersonID(1);
 GetContactInfoResponse c = stub.getContactInfo(atn);
 System.out.println(c.get_return()); //returns null

 // The Java Class that serves as the basis for the web service works well...
 PersonalInfoService s = new PersonalInfoService(); 
 System.out.println(s.getContactInfo(1).getStreet()); //returns main street
```

This is all very new for me (I am still pretty dependent on following the tutorial) so I am not sure what might be causing this issue or how I might go about debugging what's wrong. What might be causing the problem and how would I go about debugging it?

If I try to call the webservice in the broswer using this url:
  `http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/PersonalInfoService/getContactInfo?personID=1`
I get this

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <ns:getContactInfoResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.com">
    <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    </ns:getContactInfoResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your client code is okay. The response from the server just doesn't contain any data. The simplest explanation is that the server sent back a response without any data. If I were you, I'd troubleshoot the server's behavior when it receives this request, rather than focusing on the client code.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with **Wireshark** or **tcpdump**, this will help you capturing Network traffic that will help you debug at application and transport level what your Java code is generating and the response from server.